# Update DbSet.Local after row deletion in the database

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I have a DbSet associated to a DbContext (with Entity Framework 4.3). 
The DbSet is initially loaded with all the entities of a given table X
The problem is that I'm not able to Reload the DbSet to get a frech list of the table X after the deletion of one or several rows of that table (deletion done by another DbContext in another application).

Here is the line I'm using to reload all the entities of my table:

```
 ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, col);
```

That line is working correctly for retrieving added entities or changed entities.

I also can not dispose the DbContext to get frech entities because my DbContext is also carrying another entities and it would be too long to reload them all (I know I'm not following the rule that say : DbContext should be used as a transnational objet)

Comment: ref: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2e1fa691-7b6a-4586-904d-ada69540a809/dbcontextlocal-does-not-remove-entities-that-have-been-deleted-from-the-database-via-a-different. No working solution shared there, but many ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "clear" the `Local` collection and subsequently reload it:

```
foreach (var x in context.Set<X>().Local.ToList())
{
    Entry(x).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
context.Set<X>().Load();
```

You can't do `context.Set<X>().Local.Clear();`, because that marks all items in the collection as `Deleted` and the items will not be reloaded.

(Courtesy [Code First: problem with Local collection](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5e22135a-f48a-491e-8d95-c508b1815dd1/code-first-problem-with-local-collection)).

Comment: This didn't quite work for me (I am using EF Core 2... I'm not sure if that makes the difference). Calling `context.Set<X>()` causes the application to query the database and fetch the new collection of items, so the deleted items never get detached. You need to iterate over `context.Set<X>().Local`. Remember to copy it to a local variable using ToArray() or ToList() first, because setting the state to "Detached" will remove the item from the Local collection. If the Local collection is modified while you are iterating over it, you'll get an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: @CollinK Seeing this old answer of mine I wonder why nobody noticed the error. It should have been `context.Set<X>().Local.ToList()` from the outset. That should also work with EF-core.